# How to solve async connection issue of paho mqtt client?

Tags: java, asynchronous, mqtt, paho

**Background**

I have been playing with MQTT for a project and encountered a odd issue. I am using [`paho`](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/) as my MQTT client and [`VerneMQ`](https://vernemq.com) as broker.

VerneMQ broker service is up and running, I can confirm this by runnnig `netstat` and I can see that `127.0.0.1:1883` entry is in `LISTENING` mode.

This is my code for client:

```
public class Producer implements MqttCallback {

    private String brokerUri;
    private String clientId;

    public Producer(String brokerUri, String clientId){
        this.brokerUri = brokerUri;
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public void doProduce(String topic, String payload){
        MemoryPersistence memoryPersistence = new MemoryPersistence();

        try {
            MqttAsyncClient mqttAsyncClient = new MqttAsyncClient(brokerUri, clientId, memoryPersistence);
            MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
            mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
            mqttAsyncClient.setCallback(this);
            mqttAsyncClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions);
            MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage();
            mqttMessage.setPayload(payload.getBytes());
            mqttAsyncClient.publish(topic, mqttMessage);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

    }


    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {

    }


    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        System.out.println("Message delivered!");
    }
}
```

The following is my Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Producer producer = new Producer("tcp://127.0.0.1:1883", "producer1");
        producer.doProduce("dummyTopic", "dummyMessage");
    }
}
```

**Issue**

When I run my application, I see `Client is not connected (32104)` exception in the output.

If I change the line `mqttAsyncClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions);` to `mqttAsyncClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions).waitForCompletion();` in `Producer` class, I can successfully connect to broker and I can see `Message delivered!` in the output.

If I am not mistaken `waitForCompletion()` will block the call until a response is received. And by adding this line I have effectively changed my AsyncClient connection to blocking connection, which is not the desired approach for me.

**Question**

How can I resolve this issue so paho MQTT client connects to broker in a non-blocking fashion? Have I missed something along the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This covered in the documentation for the [IMqttAsyncClient](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/IMqttAsyncClient.html)

> ```
>  IMqttToken token method(parms, Object userContext, IMqttActionListener callback)
> ```
>
> In this form a callback is registered with the method. The callback
>   will be notified when the action succeeds or fails. The callback is
>   invoked on the thread managed by the MQTT client so it is important
>   that processing is minimised in the callback. If not the operation of
>   the MQTT client will be inhibited. For example to be notified (called
>   back) when a connect completes:
>
> ```
> IMqttToken conToken;
>   conToken = asyncClient.connect("some context", new MqttAsyncActionListener() {
>       public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
>         log("Connected");
>       }
>
>       public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
>         log ("connect failed" +exception);
>       }
> });
> ```
>
> An optional context object can be passed into the method which will
>   then be made available in the callback. The context is stored by the
>   MQTT client) in the token which is then returned to the invoker. The
>   token is provided to the callback methods where the context can then
>   be accessed.

So your try/catch block should look like this:

```
try {
  MqttAsyncClient mqttAsyncClient = new MqttAsyncClient(brokerUri, clientId, memoryPersistence);
  MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
  mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
  mqttAsyncClient.setCallback(this);
  mqttAsyncClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new MqttAsyncActionListener() {
    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
      MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage();
      mqttMessage.setPayload(payload.getBytes());
      mqttAsyncClient.publish(topic, mqttMessage);
    }

    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
});

} catch (MqttException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```